# array logic : How can i arrange two array numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays:

`int array1 [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};` [This array can grow to huge numbers]

`int array2 [] = {1,2,3};` [Max it can have is 30 elements]

array1 should be the parent loop and will have more elements than array2. For example I have to arrange like below :

Expected result :
1-1
2-2
3-3
4-1
5-2
6-3
7-1

How can I proceed?

Comment: @Trobbins This is a little more complicated than "nested loops", but it also isn't really appropriate as an SO question IMO.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a nested loop in this case; all you need is proper use of the modulus operator.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(array1[i] + "-" + array2[i % array2.length]);
}
```

The reason this works is that the modulus operator maps very nicely to your problem. The operation you're trying to perform requires repeatedly iterating through a list (`array2`) and wrapping back to the beginning. The modulus operator is, in essence, a "wrapping" operator; thinking incrementally, it allows you to go back to 0 every time you reach a certain number (in this case, the size of `array2`).

Comment: You've answer the question correctly! You have solved Santanu's homework.  Perhaps you should add an explanation on WHY this works.  Then I will upvote instead of downvote.

Comment: Apologies. I'll update the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Hmm, so I edit my answer to match the updated question more closely, and it gets downvoted? StackOverflow, you surely are a curious beast.

Comment: Same here RedRobo, even though yours is better than mine

Answer (score 1):

So you have two sets, you want to loop through each element of the larger set (array1) and for each element of the set print the element, and the next element of set2 (array2).

I used an [enhanced for loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm), it loops over each element, and then [modulus](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html) witch effectively limits `i` to be less than the length of set2. (remainder must be less than 3 if dividing by 3)

This allows us to add one to `i` using `i++` and be assured that it will always loop back around  to the first element as if the value were on a [spinner](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhgcPeDAEj1DYcXDl9010Mp7Xs4l1neXK901FuvuAfFQKB4PXw).

```
  int i = 0;
  for( int value : array1 ) {
     System.out.print( value + "-" + array2[i++ % array2.length] );
  }
```

Comment: This is inelegant (and therefore error-prone) because it requires both the internal index of the enhanced `for` loop and your manual `i` index.

Comment: Yep, I was going to do something closer to yours but I couldn't remember how java handled modulus.

Comment: You've answer the question correctly! You have solved Santanu's homework. Perhaps you should add an explanation on WHY this works. Then I will upvote instead of downvote.